# YII2 Setting selected value in DropDownlist in update page

Tags: php, yii2

I created a CRUD application using the GII tool and it work well. In the `_form.php`, I edited the dropdown for province, municipality, and barangay like the following...

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'province')
         ->dropDownList([ '160200000' => 'AGUSAN DEL NORTE', 
                          '160300000' => 'AGUSAN DEL SUR',
                          '166700000' => 'SURIGAO DEL NORTE', 
                          '166800000' => 'SURIGAO DEL SUR',
                          '168500000' =>'DINAGAT ISLANDS'
                        ], 
                        ['prompt' => '-----SELECT PROVINCE-----']
          )?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'city_code')
         ->dropDownList(['' => '-----SELECT PROVINCE FIRST-----'])?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'brgy_code')
         ->dropDownList(['' => '-----SELECT MUNICIPALITY FIRST-----'])?>
```

Using Jquery I was able to change the values in the municipality dropdown according to the province selected. And so on with the brgy.

However in the Index file, when I click the pencil icon or the EDIT link in the gridview, It shows all the equivalent values but not the province, municipality, and brgy. How can I change these values from the update.php file?

Comment: So you want to set selected value in `province` drop-down list according to model value?

Comment: `var_dump` model `province` value, what it contains?

Comment: nothing. It is a related data. I can get province via `$model->cityCode->province->prov_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set selected value then you need set it like this for edit

`$model->cityCode->province=array_keys(CHtml::listData($resultset,'provinceid', 'provinceid'))`;

I hope this will help you.
 For yii2 ex

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'sex',array('1'=>'men','2'=>'women'), array('options' => array('2'=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

Comment: what is that `$resultset`, `provinceid`,.. Do you have a brief explanation?

Comment: CHtml sound like Yii 1. Question was about Yii 2.